# Why is the Image Handler not called with an AJAX client?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, image

Please see the code below:

```
Public Class Default4
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim image1 As Image = Default4.GetSQLTable
        OtherBits.Controls.Add(image1)
    End Sub

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetSQLTable() As Image
        Dim Image1 As New Microsoft.Web.GeneratedImage
        Image1.ImageHandlerUrl = "ImageHandler1.ashx?id=1"
        Return Image1
    End Function

End Class
```

After the code runs there is an image on the webpage (OtherBits is a Placeholder).

I want to retrieve the image on the client side using AJAX i.e. AJAX will call a function (get SQL table), which calls the image handler.  Here is the client side code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/LGMaster.master" CodeBehind="Default4.aspx.vb" Inherits="com.app.PresentationLayer.Web.Default4" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">




     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">

        function GetSQLTable() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default4.aspx/GetSQLTable",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess(),
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert('there was an error loading the webpage')
                    }
                });
            function OnSuccess() {
                return function (response) {
                       document.getElementById('test_div').innerHTML = response.d;
                }
            }
        }
        window.onload = GetSQLTable
    </script> 

    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <div id="test_div">
    </div>

        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="OtherBits" />

    </asp:Content>
```

I have placed a breakpoint inside the ImageHandler and can confirm that it is not called if the client is AJAX.  Why is the Image Handler not called with an AJAX client? All calls to the Image Handler are logged.  I can confirm that it is definitely not called.

Comment: Is the AJAX request being invoked at all?  What is the server's response?

Comment: @David, thanks.  I have placed a breakpoint in GetSQLTable (server side function).  It is definetly called by Ajax.  The server side function (GetSQLTable) is not calling the ImageHandler.

Comment: I'm not certain what a `Microsoft.Web.GeneratedImage` is, but I wouldn't expect this server-side code to "call the image handler".  Would this just return some markup and the browser would then send a request to the image handler based on the URL?  Is your `OnSuccess` client-side function invoked?  What's in `response.d`?  Are you successfully updating the markup as you expect?

Comment: Sorry, this was my terminology.  The image is created in the code behind and added to a placeholder.  The server side code does not call the ImageHandler directly.

Comment: At that point you're back to client-side debugging, where things like "placeholders" don't exist.  Have you done any debugging in the client-side success handler?  You need to ensure that the client-side markup (your `test_div` element) is being updated the way you expect it to.

Comment: @david, the problem is on the server side. The image handler is not being called so a red cross appears on the screen. I have tested this with a plain asp.net page i.e. A webpage that contains no placeholders.

Comment: There's no evidence in the information so far to guarantee that the problem is server-side, I suspect you're just assuming that.  If this server-side code *is* being called and *is* returning something to the client and the client is *not* calling the image handler, then your next debugging step is *on the client*.

Comment: It may still be on the client side, if the URL for the ImageHandler is incorrect.  Can you navigate to the URL - the one that is actually rendered on the Image control - in a browser?

Comment: @Ann L, thanks.  Yes, I can manually browse to the URL.  The URL is correct.

Comment: @w0051977  And this is the URL *that gets rendered on your page*?  Not the one that you *intend* to have rendered, but the actual URL that appears in the source attribute on the rendered Image tag?  It occurs to me that "ImageHandler1.ashx?id=1" (as opposed to, say, "~/ImageHandler1.ashx?id=1") may not result in a proper URL being generated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think maybe it's related to limitation of Shared functions (as i say i'm not sure)
but do you try to create image in ASHX, remove GetSQLTable totally and set ajax URL to:

```
url: "ImageHandler1.ashx?id=1",
```

instead of :

```
url: "Default4.aspx/GetSQLTable",
```

Why the GetSQLTable is neccessary?